# KeyVaultClient and KeyVaultCredentials not present in new SDKs

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-java-sdk

We were using KeyVaultClient and KeyVaultCredentials classes as provided in the SDK -
com.microsoft.azure
azure-keyvault

Recently got a warning that this library is deprecated and is divided into 3 libraries - azure-keyvault-security-certificates, azure-keyvault-security-secrets and azure-keyvault-security-keys but I could not find these classes in any of the libraries. Am I still supposed to use azure-keyvault for these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what functionality of Key Vault you want to use, instead of a `KeyVaultClient` you would use a [`CertificateClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-certificates#create-certificate-client), [`KeyClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-keys#create-key-client) or [`SecretClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-secrets#create-secret-client).

For example, you can instantiate a simple client the following way:

```java
KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl("<your-key-vault-url>")
    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
    .buildClient();
```

There are many more methods you can use in a client builder to customize the resulting client.

As for a replacement for `KeyVaultCredentials`, client builders allow you to authenticate the client to be created via the `credential()` method, so you can choose the way that best fits your solution. For more information on the available credential types and their diffecences you can check the [Azure Identity README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity#credentials).